# php website mobile version, image shows sideways when uploaded

Tags: php, mobile, upload

I am using this code to upload a picture from my mobile on my php website mobile version. The problem is for a strange reason the image get rotated. I need a solution as I have been trying in vain till now.

The code I am using for my php site is :

```
<?php    
if (isset($_FILES["pics"]["name"]) ) 
{
  $errors= array();
  foreach($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
  {
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['pics']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['pics']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['pics']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['pics']['type'][$key]; 
    $file_name1[] = $file_name;        
    $desired_dir="users/timeline/".$_SESSION['session_uid'];
    if(empty($errors)==true)
    {
      if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
      {
        mkdir("$desired_dir", 0777);  // Create directory if it does not exist
      }
      if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
      {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
      }
      else
      {         // rename the file if another one exist
        $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
        rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;    

      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

HELP PLEASE :)

Comment: The code above has applies no rotation. On some mobile devices, the images are all stored in the original orientation but rotated when viewing. There may be some meta data that has orientation... not sure.

Comment: yes the code does not have any rotation but mobile (all phones) roate it, What meta could effect this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, did some Googling. Your code is fine, the image is rotated before it is upload. I am assuming you are using an iPhone so here is a great resource to help you with your problem:

http://iphonephotographyschool.com/iphone-photos-upside-down/

From the link above:

"Your iPhone doesn’t convert any images to correct orientation because that would keep it busy for a few seconds. Instead it simply saves all photos as they were recorded and adds information about their correct orientation to EXIF tags. This means that your iPhone is ready to shoot another photo within a fraction of a second, which is just awesome."

Comment: Hi MAtt its not Iphone, the problem is with all mobile phones.

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: its a mobile version of a regular website and have tried uploading pictures using, BLACKBERRY, Iphone 4, Samsung and Q MOBILE ANDRIOD. Lot of uploaded pictures for a strange reason show sideways.

Comment: Are the photos taken in landscape mode, or is it all random?

Comment: random but I am having problem with Portrait showing sideways for example my picture when uploaded on mobile shows head on left side of the picture and feet on right side (thats how it shows on all images and being referred as "FLIPPED sideways" by me)

Comment: Can you share the front end code you are using to upload to the website?

Comment: <?php 
    session_start();
    $querypost = "SELECT * FROM posts order by postid desc ";
    
 $sql_post =  mysql_query($querypost) or die($querypost);

    $rowphoto= mysql_fetch_array($sql_photo);
   
    $photo=explode(",",$rowphoto['photos']);

     for ($i=0;$i<count($photo); $i++)
    {
    if($i%4==0)

     {
   echo "<br>"; 
 
     }
  ?>
     <img src="users/timeline/<?php echo $_SESSION['session_uid'];?>/<?php echo $photo[$i]; ?>"  style="height:auto" width="100px"   hspace="5px" vspace="5px;"/>
 <?php

     }

  ?>

Comment: This is displaying from the database. Where is the code that allows the user to select a photo, then press upload.

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>
         <input type="file" name="pics[]" id="pics22"  value=""  />
        </label>
        <div id="showprogressphoto" style="display:none" align="center"><img src="images/ajax-loader-tr.gif" /></div>
       <label>
       <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="Submit" onClick="return validate3();" />
       </label>
    </form>

Comment: hey Matt, any help bro?